# Solve the recurrence $a_{n+2}=5a_{n+1}-9a_n+3n$?

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

What is the simplest way to solve the recurrence $a_{n+2}=5a_{n+1}-9a_n+3n$, with the initial values $a_0=2,a_1=1$? Is it possible to do this with generating functions?

Answer (score 3):

There're at least <s>two</s> *four* commonly used methods:

1. generating functions
2. looking for solutions in a particular form: $n^k\alpha^n$ with $k\in\mathbb N$ and $\alpha\in\Bbb R$.
3. [Z-transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform). Thank you, @Omnomnomnom.
4. The annihiliator method/characteristic equations (even though they are closely related to the second method). Thank you, @anorton.

The [wikipedia article on recurrence relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation) can give you a couple of ideas.

Comment: There's also the [Z-transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform)

Comment: Don't forget the method of annihilators along with characteristic equations. `:)`

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thank you, I added it to my post.

Comment: @anorton thank you, I added it to my post.

Answer (score 0):

solve the equation $$a_{n+2}=5a_{n+1}-9a_n$$ with the ansatz $$a_n=q^n$$ and look for a special solution of the equation $$a_{n+2}=5a_{n+1}-9a_n+3n$$